# Connect to mssql from sqlalchemy by pyodbc on mac os

Tags: python, macos, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, turbogears2

Anyone has successfully connect to mssql thru pyodbc within sqlalchemy? I am using turbogears2 right now, and try to connect to mssql, working on a mac os platform.

Getting following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (Error) ('00000', '[00000] [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen({SQL Server}, 6): image not found (0) (SQLDriverConnectW)') None None
```

Comment: where's the code you're trying to run?

Comment: also, did you install any odbc drivers for mssql?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
Here are some sample codes I used in python shell directly:

>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> engine=sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://sa:password@host/hf_export')
>>> con=engine.connect()

Comment: I think you are right, maybe I am missing the ODBC driver, I have pyodbc installed, apparently, it's not a driver.

Comment: Did you find a driver for OSX?

Comment: Yes, I did, I used freedts, following are some notes I made when I worked on it, it's painful and I have gave up python on that project due to some reasons, anyway, hope the information can help:

Answer (score 4):

There is a better approach than the old macports or fink, [brew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/):

```
brew install freetds unixodbc
```

And it doesn't even need root to install it.

Answer (score 2):

### Easy way by MacPort

Simply do the installation by:

```
    sudo port install freetds +mssql +odbc +universal
```

This will install both freetds and unixODBC, we can either using unixODBC for ODBC management, or using iODBC shipped with Mac OS.

### Compile and installation

```
    ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/lib/freetds --with-tdsver=8.0 --enable-msdblib --enable-dbmfix --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-static
    make
    make install
```

### TDSVER setting

For connecting to SQL Server 2005/8, make sure setting the tds version to 8.0, use following terminal command:

```
    export TDSVER = 8.0
```

### Lauguange setting

Make sure right language has been setted:

```
    export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: What directory should be I be in for the ./configure command?